# Jquery Mobile Datepicker, Choose date and display events

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, web-applications, datepicker, datebox

I have a table with activities and the frequency they are repeated (Mon,Tue, etc)
The mobile web page I have will display the details for today. I want to add a datepicker button to a navbar on the page.

The following code gets the information for 'today'

```
//todays date
$current_day = date('N');

echo "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //if the event is on today then print the details
    if(strpos($row['Day'], $current_day) !== false){
        echo "<li>";

        echo "<h1>".$row['Start']." - ".$row['End']."</h1>";
        echo "<h2>".$row['Class']."</h2>";
        echo "<h2>".$row['Instructor']."</h2>";

        echo "</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

I would like to use a date picker to set the current day to the user's choice.
I have tried using Jquery Mobile Date Box but can't figure out how to use the date that way.
([Using the CalBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQM datebox as follows:

Create an `input` with `type="date"` and set the mode as desired. If you want to respond to the new date as soon as the user sets it, you can add a callback for `closeCallback`.

```
<input name="Date1" id="Date1" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "closeCallback": "onClose" }' /> 

function onClose(){
    alert($('#Date1').datebox('getTheDate').getDay());
}
```

You can also just get the date later, say when a button is clicked:

```
$('#btndatebox').on('click', function () {
    var currDate = $('#Date1').datebox('getTheDate').getDay();
    alert(currDate);
});
```

`getDay()` is the javascript function for getting the day of the week from a date object.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/tx7k6/1/)**

Comment: This seems to do the job. Is there a way to get it without the Date bar. that is just the calendar button? Also to get tomorrow and yesterday with button clicks?
Sorry for the add on questions. this does answer my original question perfectly though. Thank you

Comment: You have been such a great help! Is it possible to take the value being created from getDay() and pass it to a php variable?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know php. You have the value as a javascript variable, you could also write it to an invisible DOM element if that helps...